# ParseCrashReporting iOS linker error

Tags: ios, linker-errors

I was trying to enable parse crash reporting. However there is always linker error when compiling. I have tried the method in other thread, like adding libstdc++6.0.9 other than libstdc++6.

The error message is:

```
Ld /Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foodmate-bmbrourdyfbrskdmdpojqnvszznk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foodmate.app/Foodmate normal x86_64
cd /Users/Peter/Dropbox/work/foodmate/iOS/HomeMade
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foodmate-bmbrourdyfbrskdmdpojqnvszznk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foodmate-bmbrourdyfbrskdmdpojqnvszznk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Peter/Dropbox/work/foodmate/iOS/HomeMade -F/Users/Peter/Dropbox/work/foodmate/iOS/HomeMade/HomeMade -F/Users/Peter/Desktop/Foodmate/iOS/lib -F/Users/Peter/Dropbox/work/foodmate/iOS/HomeMade/HomeMade/ActionSheetPicker-3.0-master/ObjC-Example -F/Users/Peter/Dropbox/work/foodmate/iOS/lib -F/Users/Peter/Dropbox/work/foodmate/iOS/HomeMade/HomeMade/parse -filelist /Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foodmate-bmbrourdyfbrskdmdpojqnvszznk/Build/Intermediates/Foodmate.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foodmate.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Foodmate.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -lsqlite3 -lstdc++.6 -framework ParseCrashReporting -framework StoreKit -framework CoreLocation -framework ParseFacebookUtils /Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foodmate-bmbrourdyfbrskdmdpojqnvszznk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGPUImage.a -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Parse -framework ParseUI -framework Social -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework MobileCoreServices -lz -framework ParseFacebookUtilsV4 -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -framework Accounts -framework Bolts -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foodmate-bmbrourdyfbrskdmdpojqnvszznk/Build/Intermediates/Foodmate.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foodmate.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Foodmate_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Foodmate-bmbrourdyfbrskdmdpojqnvszznk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foodmate.app/Foodmate

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFDevice", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseCrashReporting(PFCrashReporter.o)

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFLogger", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseCrashReporting(ParseCrashReporting.o)
  objc-class-ref in ParseCrashReporting(PFCrashReporter.o)
  objc-class-ref in ParseCrashReporting(PFCrashReportingAnalytics.o)

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFRESTAnalyticsCommand", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseCrashReporting(PFCrashReportingAnalytics.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem.
The problem is actually caused by an incorrect library path in buildPath. So xcode search the path first and used an order version of Parse.framework

Answer (score 0):

Are these in another framework or static library that is not being linked to the app?

- PFDevice
- PFLogger
- PFRESTAnalyticsCommand

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I have added all the required library listed on parseCrashReporting document page.

Answer (score 0):

That link error means that you are using the PFDevice, PFLogger, and PFRESTAnalyticsCommand classes, but you are not linking in any object files, libraries, or frameworks that provide the implementation of those classes.  You need to add a link against those when building.  If using Xcode, select the framework that provides the class and check the box to add it to your target (or drag it into your link phase).  It you already are linking against it, the message may also mean that your framework does not have an x86_64 slice.

Answer (score 0):

Re-add last versions Parse.framework, ParseCrashReporting.framework and Bolts.framework to your Project.